# Discord.py - which way should I pick?

Tags: python, pycharm, discord, discord.py, bots

Recently I've known that developers are able to code Discord.py bot in 2 ways (or even more):

1. To code every command as `if message.content.startswith("hello"):`
2. Or to code every command as `async def hello(ctx):`

So, which type is more productive and better?
Thank you

Comment: I guess using `commands` will be better at some point but that is just my own opinion. `on_message` events just have `message` as an argument, `commands` can be more versatile. As a beginner `on_message` events are probably more typical.

Comment: use whatever you like. You can even use both methods at the same time. `commands` was created to make life simpler so I would choose `command` - it checks prefix and `if message ...` so I don't have to do it. But if I need something unusual then I can still use ` on_message`. In one answer I created example which uses `on_message` to run one command without prefix and other commands still need prefix.

Comment: Just use `commands`, they are better to handle and easily manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need commands, use the commands extension.
**Docs:** https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

**Why should I use the commands extension?**

- Prevents spaghetti code
- Better performance
- Easy handling and processing of command arguments
- Argument type converters
- Easy subcommands
- Command cooldowns
- Built-in help function
- Easy prefix management
- Command checks, for controlling when they're to be invoked
- Ability to add command modules via extensions/cogs
- Still able to do everything you can do with the first way